# Xcode Scheme with multiple targets creates Generic Xcode Archive

Tags: ios, xcode

Ok, I am almost certain that this thing worked before but I am stuck now...

I have a workspace with multiple targets which I want to archive and submit to appstore simultaneously.

I have created a new scheme, I have all targets selected in there for Archive and I try to execute Archive in order to make all targets to IPAs

I always end up getting an Xcode Generic Archive. The only case I am getting an IPA is to select Skip Install = YES for all targets but one each time, which I suppose it actually means to build just one target so there is no meaning to multi target scheme.

Any clues about that? I checked the size of this Generic Archive and it looks like all apps combined in one file.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need to archive one by one individually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed Apple confirmed that this is "impossible because archiving step in a scheme is designed to produce only one archive" and they asked me to build every target separately. I wonder if I can archive every scheme in a workspace automatically from command line to produce the desired result.

Answer (score -3):

In order to create an IPA file using Xcode, we can use commands too. One can follow these steps: 
1. Navigate to the App folder in Terminal
2. Run Cordova build command using "cordova build iOS" command
3. Open your iOS Project in Xcode.
4. Choose Product -> Clean. Then Archive.

More detailed screenshots are available [here](http://virteom.com/how-to-create-an-ipa-file-using-xcode).